# How to enter a character in a C program in windows without display on screen and also without pausing the screen?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a game program in C.
How to get a char or input without displaying and pausing the screen?

Comment: Please look up the curses or ncurses  libraries. Also multi theading

Comment: There is nothing like that in the C language, you need to use your platform APIs.

Comment: Plain C can't do that, so you'll need some platform-specific library.

Comment: You'll need to specify the platform you're working on.  The answers for Windows will be different from the answer for Unix-based systems.  On Unix-like systems, use the `curses` or `ncurses` library, or the [`<termios.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/termios.h.html) header and functions such as [`tcgetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html) and [`tcsetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetattr.html).

Comment: There is an `ncurses` port for MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you want to make a game in C.

Create your own window.
Capture and Process events.

This sounds a bit much for a beginner but actually it is not.
Use a library like SDL2 to help you with that.

Here is a [tutorial series](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/) that walks you through some of the basics of game making.